# excel, without script, just using its built in features, how to trigger a value or content in one cell based on value or content in other cell

Tags: excel

Need advice on the following; Thanks in advance.:
[Excel, the visual description of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0Tpb.png)

**Further description of the issue:**
certain Product code = certain Product name of certain Size. 
The help-table on the attached image shows that a certain product code = what product name of what size, as a guide.

**This is what I try to do. This is what my question is: How to achieve: 
Manual entry in cells of column A should trigger automatically filled content in cells of columns B and C based on the content of A and based on the dependencies described in the help-Table.**

**Edited: As the user proceeds adding new records in new rows, the appropriate columns (B and C) should "fill itself" automatically as soon as there's an entry in the same row in column A. This automatically filled content in column C and B depends on what is the content of column A as can be seen on the attached image("help-table"). And all this should work without me using a formula in columns B and C.**

So far I used an "IF" formula which is not practical for many possible product codes. 
A formula is also impractical as its usage requires the formula to be copied to next row, **which I want to avoid. I want the set rule to be applied to a whole column.(for example as the data validation or conditional formatting work in excel)**

*It would be ideal to use it in a way like the conditional formatting works*, but in this case it should work with values(content) instead of colors and should be applicable for an entire column without a need of copying to the next row. That means I'd like to avoid macros or VBA if possible, just want to use built in features.

I already use *Defined names* and *Data validation* for columns A,B and C which works for me as a choice list and also to control column B and C for allowed entries only, so their content is not mistyped and has the strict format needed. Excel 2010 -if that matters.

**Important:** there will be 1000's of rows added, I just made a short description above

Formula for cells in column B:

```
=IF(A2=10,"prod1",IF(A2=20,"prod1",IF(A2=30,"prod2",IF(A2=40,"prod2",""))))
```

Formula for cells in column C:

```
=IF(A2=10,"50",IF(A2=20,"75",IF(A2=30,"10",IF(A2=40,"50",""))))
```

Also tried a CSE formula for the entire column B or C like follows (but the file size was couple of MB which is not desired):

```
=IF(A:A=10,"prod1",IF(A:A=20,"prod1",IF(A:A=30,"prod2",IF(A:A=40,"prod2",""))))
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: see [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65). Also available in [Our 10 most popular functions](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Excel-functions-by-category-5f91f4e9-7b42-46d2-9bd1-63f26a86c0eb). Also [Use formulas in an Excel table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-formulas-in-an-Excel-table-C8483716-96FA-4111-A35D-005B41263062).

Comment: VLOOKUP is definitely more handy than my IF's and seem to do the work with 3 exceptions: 
1- it's a formula "way" so it has to be copied to the whole column, which is a requirement. Want to set the "rule"(formula) for a whole column so as they proceed in adding new records in new rows the appropriate column would "fill itself"
2- the result is a massive file size.
3- the appearance; for empty columns of A there's "#N/A" which doesn't look "nice"
Thanks anyway.

Comment: This VLOOKUP seem to be the most elegant way so far to achieve what I want, but I don't want to put this formula into each cell of a column. So I wonder if it's possible to include VLOOKUP into DataValidation somehow (with some modification) so I achieve what I really need? Or is it a no-go this way?

Answer (score 0):

If the entry in column A will be only 10,20,30 and 40 then use **[OR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OR-function-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0)** formula in column B

```
=IF(OR(A2=10,A2=20),"prod1","prod2")
```

In Column C we can reduce two IF

```
=IF(A2=20,"75",IF(A2=30,"10","50"))
```

And regarding the file size please save it in [binary](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Save-a-workbook-in-another-file-format-eb019937-6842-4412-8046-112cc6948d08) format. Hope this will help :)

Comment: Outside this example I posted, there's about 33 product codes, 27 product names and 3 sizes.

Your tips seem to work, though still need to figure out the logic.
There are few properties which I'd like to avoid though, if possible -same as I wrote for VLOOKUP above. Still need to have a look at the binary format...too

Comment: Click on the "binary" text link you will get to know and explain what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Binary roughly halved my file (6.5MB) compared to xlsx(15.2MB), but still too big for emailing, especially in the future when there will be lot of rows of records. No records currently in the file, just the column titles, a few DefinedNames and DataValidatons and the formulas in C & B prepared for use. The size's inflated because the formula is copied to the whole column B & C. Without the formula in whole column B & C the file is just 21kB. That's also the reason I'd like to go on it a bit different way. It's going to be basically a log-file, where a user will record stuff and email it in.

Comment: In that case while sending it remove the formula by copy pasting it as values

Comment: I understand that it works that way, but considering it's sent to few different users and ask them to do this repeatedly doesn't seem to be a efficient, safe nor convenient way and also could introduce errors if done incorrectly. Briefly I'd like to avoid users doing stuff affecting the functionality and want them just to fill new lines of new info... 
**Any idea if possible to implement that VLOOKUP into DataValidation or something similar?**

Comment: I will try.. In other ways you can zip the file and sent it in mails

Comment: For excel binary format it's ok to zip, 624kB, the xlsx it's 6MB. Though would prefer to exclude zipping because of the userexperience, if there's a simpler way.