# Vlookup in Excel, to auto-fill content in a column's cell based on content of other column's cell

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

**Further description of the issue:** certain Product code = certain Product name of certain Size. The help-table on the attached image shows that a certain product code = what product name of what size, as a guide.

**My question is, How to achieve with VBA (or macro):** Manual entry in cells of column A should trigger automatically filled content in cells of columns B and C based on the content of A and based on the dependencies described in the help-Table. (using Vlookup possibly)

As the user proceeds adding new records in new rows, the appropriate cell of columns (B and C) should "fill itself" automatically as soon as there's an entry in the same row in column A. This automatically filled content in cell of column C and B depends on what is the content of cell in column A as can be seen on the attached image("help-table"). And all this should work without me using a formula in columns B and C. For empty cells in column A there should be nothing in cells of column B and C, not even #N/A displayed.

I already use Defined names and Data validation for columns A,B and C which works for me as a choice list and also to control column B and C for allowed entries only, so their content is not mis-typed and has the strict format needed. Excel 2010 -if that matters.

*Important:* there will be 1000's of rows added, I just made a short description above.

Currently I'm using a CSE formula for column B

```
{=VLOOKUP(A:A,$H$2:$J$5,2)}
```

and for column C

```
{=VLOOKUP(A:A,$H$2:$J$5,3)}
```

*The issue is a massive file size and a display of #N/A in empty rows. From using macro/VBA I hope for a small file size and clean look.*

I can't do macros neither VBA, so if you could be so kind and put up the whole code, please. Thanks.

I tried to get help for doing this without programming [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34062929/excel-without-script-just-using-its-built-in-features-how-to-trigger-a-value), without success so far.

Comment: `And all this should work without me using a formula in columns B and C.` I believe is not possible without vba.  Putting `IFError(Vlookup(A2,$H$2:$J$5,2),"")` in B2 and `IFError(Vlookup(A2,$H$2:$J$5,3),"")` in C2 and copying down will do it.

Comment: You can remove the #N/A by adding a `IF(ISNA(Formula),"", Formula)`. This will essencially erase the NAs. Thats a part of your solution.

Comment: Have you considered making this a list object (structured) table with auto-formula-fill?

Comment: The intention of this post is to get solution using VBA or macro, I thought it's clear from the question. My other post mentioned at the bottom was for non programmed version.

Comment: You are not likely to get the full code written for you here.  SO is not a code for me service.  If you have attempts at the code please post it with a specific question of what is going wrong and we will help.  Otherwise by your example all three of the formulas given will do it without code.

Comment: @SontNeil - you've asked someone to write it from scratch for you. That's not going to happen on this site - as per my comment below, it's not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Non-vba wise, however, you can't do everything you've asked for here. Sorry. Instead, as a non-vba example, I'd suggest you use the product key column (A) to fill columns B and C. B and C would have to have an Index-Match formula in, with a iferror outside it to keep it clean - Like this

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($I$2:$I$4,MATCH($A2,$H$2:H$4,0)),"")
```

(This example would sit in cell B2)

EDIT:

An extra point: if size is really a huge issue, I'd suggest either looking into PowerPivot and learning some of that (try [Excelisfun](https://www.youtube.com/user/ExcelIsFun) on youtube for a quick start - assuming it's relevant, it may even save you creating this spread sheet at all).

Alternatively, and assuming you don't need the details to change dynamically, simply copy paste the relevant completed fields as values - this will remove the formulas. you'll need to ensure that any further additions refer the same formula so either save it elsewhere on the sheet as plaintext - you can do this by adding any character before the =
(My personal favourite is the uptick ` as I don't use it otherwise).

Comment: Comment removed from answer: "
I would first note that Stack Exchange is not a code-writing service. Its a q+a service, designed for asking specific questions about specific parts of code. If you want someone to write this for you, pay a consultant to do it or use your google-fu to find an example where someone has already done this for you."

Comment: @SontNeil Some people contribute more than what the site is intended for - but this should be seen as generosity on behalf of the contributor, and cases where it happens does not mean the same can be demanded for every question.

Comment: @SontNeil, VBA is an eminently learnable language. It took me less than a week learning it to get to the point where I could have a good bash at what I want it to do and go from there. And VBA was my first foray into coding. When I get stuck I come here and ask for help from the community here. What the site here is NOT for is coding to spec on demand for no recompense. Given that writing the code you want would take a significant amount of time, and also that I have just given you a usable, non-code solution, you'll forgive me if I decline your generous offer of writing your code for you.

Comment: @SontNeil - with regards to the link, its likely someone already had a ready made piece of code to go, in addition to Vegard's point. I'd be very surprised if they wrote it from scratch for the OP.